# Google Ads For Kids Category Ios

Tags: ios, admob, idfa, apptrackingtransparency

I have an application in kids category. It rejected when I want to upload new version. I wonder that can't we show ads in apps that belong to the kids category? Please make a suggestion.

I'm using these pods;

pod 'FirebaseCore'
pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'

the issue given is as follows;

We noticed that your Kids Category app includes analytics, advertising and collects, transmits, or has the ability to share personal information or device information with third parties. Specifically:
Your app implements the App Tracking Transparency framework, which is used when apps collect data about users and share it with third-parties for tracking purposes. Since Kids Category apps are not allowed to collect, transmit or share identifiable information with third-parties, you should not implement App Tracking Transparency in your app.

Your app includes third-party analytics or third-party advertising with the ability to collect, transmit or share identifiable information, including, for example, IDFA. We found that your app references the ASIdentifierManager API, which provides access to a user's IDFA, in the following location(s) in your binary:

•
/System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport

It would be appropriate to remove all instances of “ASIdentifierManager” from your app, even if they are not utilized in your app's functionality.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please remove this functionality or revise your app so that no personally identifiable information or device information is sent to third parties.

Resources

Learn more about our policies for Kids Category apps in App Store Review Guideline 1.3.

Comment: You can't have external ads in a kids category app. [Third sentence, second paragraph](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#kids-category)